# Why is my call-template looping forever?

Tags: xslt, recursion, parameter-passing, infinite-loop

I am converting an index string into index markers. The string may contain multiple levels, separated by colons. Each section may also have some other special symbols which need to be handled later.

My test string is "Home:Change", which should be converted into:

```
<indexterm>Home<indexterm>Change</indexterm></indexterm>
```

I have created a template without recursion (only doing one nested level) and that works fine (note that the outermost  is added before calling this template):

```
    <xsl:template name="parseindexstring">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,':')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,':')"/>
            <indexterm>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
            </indexterm>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>
```

But as I do not want to limit the processing to only one level, I decided to use recursion instead:

```
    <xsl:template name="parseindexstring">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(.,':')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,':')"/>
            <indexterm>
                <xsl:call-template name="parseindexstring">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after(.,':')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </indexterm>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>
```

This runs into an endless loop, even on the index string that has only two levels (i.e only one colon), and I cannot figure out why. I am passing the second part of the string to the nested call-template but it seems like it is always taking the string parameter of the top-level call. At least that is what it looks like if I single-step the XSL in my debugger. What am I forgetting or misunderstanding here?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are not using the `string` parameter in the template, but are using the `.` operator which refers to the current context (which I am guessing is the element containing your input string). As the current context is not changing, the expression `contains(.,':')` will always be true, and the template just processing the same context over and over again, regardless of what `string` is set to.

Try this template instead:

```
<xsl:template name="parseindexstring">
    <xsl:param name="string"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($string,':')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($string,':')"/>
            <indexterm>
                <xsl:call-template name="parseindexstring">
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,':')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </indexterm>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>       
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes. That works. If I understand it correctly, match-template changes the context to whatever is marked as selection to be handled, and call-template does not change the context. That makes perfect sense to me now. Thanks a lot for the help.